# Compile error "Outer.Nested has private access in Outer" for annotation on outer class with nested class as value

Tags: java, maven, java-8, jackson, javac

I have a pretty straightforward use case where I place a helper class (a Jackson custom serializer) as static nested class in the main class (a JSON model class). Surprisingly, this doesn't compile:

```
//                           v-- compile error here
@JsonSerialize(using = Outer.Nested.class)
public class Outer {

    // ... private members

    private static class Nested extends JsonSerializer<Outer> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Outer instance, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException {
            // ... serialization code accessing Outer's private members
        }
    }
}
```

The compile error message is

> org.example.Outer.Nested has private access in org.example.Outer

This message doesn't make sense to me, because private access to the outer class is allowed from nested classes.

What is also curious is that the compile error only occurs in Maven (which uses `javac` from an Oracle 1.8.0_201 JDK). In Eclipse, the same code compiles & runs just fine.

---

I found multiple workarounds for this problem, the best one being to change the visibility of the nested class from private to package-private. This code compiles:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = Outer.Nested.class)
public class Outer {

    // ... private members

    /*package-private*/ static class Nested extends JsonSerializer<Outer> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Outer instance, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException {
            // ... serialization code accessing Outer's private members
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for this behaviour of the `javac` compiler? Or is this simply a bug?

Comment: Wow, so I completely misunderstood the error message. What it wanted to say is "Outer.Nested is private"... So when using `javac`, annotations cannot access private members of the annotated class. Kind of makes sense.